# Using downloaded microsoft xp updates on multiple computers

Tags: windows, windows-xp, update

Is there a way to download the windows update package for windows xp and save it so that it can be applied to multiple machines? The reason I ask is because we are having to reimage a large number of pc's at work with a dell image direct image. These images seem to be without all of the updates and security patches. What I would like to do is download all of the updates once and apply them to multiple computers **without** using WSUS.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is using [**WSUS offline updater**](http://www.wsusoffline.net/). Download and generate an updater once and then apply it to multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can download individual updates through Microsoft's website.  You can then use the executables on each machine.

However, if you are reimaging 50+ machines, you should probably reimage one, update it completely and then use that for imaging the rest.  Otherwise you're in for a long week.

Comment: I am currently downloading all of the needed updates for the image using Microsoft update on the first machine. Do they store them somewhere hidden?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't remember where Windows stores downloaded updates from Windows Update.  I was actually referring to downloading them manually from Microsoft.com (Which is what Joe also said).  Nonetheless, this sounds like a giant pita...

Comment: Apparently for XP its: \WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download Don;t have an XP to hand so can;t check that sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for specific updates, you can found them at http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Home.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could download the updates from the Microsoft site. Burn them to CD or DVD or put them on a flash drive (Or a network share) and then install them manually on each computer. I can't imagine this being much fun at all though. You could possibly write a script to do it so you definitely didn't miss one.

Comment: I'd agree with Daniel, Update one and then image the rest from this. Unless there is a specific reason this can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would to use [Autopatcher](http://www.autopatcher.com/), which can download the updates you need to a local drive and then can be installed from a USB stick or CD. I would go with what the other said as well and take an image of the first machines you do as even with AutoPatcher what you would like to do would take a while.